# Averaging distinct values in one table?

Tags: sql, distinct, average

I have a table listing university program codes and grades. Some program codes are the same. I would like to average the grade for each distinct program. How can I manage this? My code so far has just gotten me to this table, but I can't see how I can operate on this ONE table?

```
SELECT s.program_code, 
       r.grade 
FROM   students s 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT e.student_id, 
                          e.module_code, 
                          IF( c.grade IS NULL, e.grade, (e.grade + c.grade)/2 ) AS grade 
                   FROM   exams e 
                          LEFT OUTER JOIN continuous_assessments c 
                                       ON e.student_id = c.student_id 
                                          AND e.module_code = c.module_code) r 
               ON s.student_id = r.student_id;
```

Comment: Do you want to use `COALESCE` instead of `IF`? What rdbms is this, MySql?

Comment: Everything above just gets me that table I mention.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work

```
select program_code, avg(e.grade + grade)
from blah blah
group by program_code
```

Comment: Sorry yea this is MySQL. The code I've given above returns the table that has program code and grade.

Comment: Actually, I've just answered my own question. It was something like this alright. I'm new to SQL and wasn't aware of the GROUP BY statement!